# Visual Studio 2010 - ASP.NET MVC3 app - SSRS on SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm a bit new to SSRS... I have an MVC3 application which I need to show SQL Server reports from a SQL Server 2005 database. Is this possible? I ask because my google searches indicated some problems with VS2008/SQL Server 2005, so wanted to know if these issues still persist for VS2010.

Also, is it pretty straight forward to embed the Report Viewer control in an MVC3 application? I've seen a few posts, but not too much details yet.

Links and feedback would be very much appreciated. Another question -- do I do the report designing directly in my web-app / report viewer? Or, do I have to design the report first (e.g. in a "Report Application")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should devide this into two different questoins. First about using reports in ASP.NET MVC which can be quite specific - I expect you will have to fall back to ASP.NET page for this case but let others with deeper understanding answer this question.

The second part is about designing the report itself. The issues you read on internet targets exactly this problematics. Reports are either created in Report Builder which is separate application with similar interface as MS Office or in Business intelligence development studio which is part of SQL server tools installation.

Business intelligence development studio is build on top of VS Studio shell. Each version of VS Studio has its own version of the shell and each Business intelligence development studio uses the shell of VS studio available in the time of its release. So for SQL Server 2005, the shell is based on VS Studio 2005 and because of that you will not see business intelligence projects and items (like reports) in VS 2010 and you will have to use Business intelligence development studio directly.

Answer (score 0):

yes, first design report and deploy on report server, then use report viewer control to render report in application.